# linking error in Visual Studio with C++ 3 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been using visual studio 2019 for making C++ OpenGL files. When I add a new header file and another .cpp file I get the following error. I am keeping vector.cpp, vector.h, and main.cpp in a file as I had before and they worked but now I have linker problems.

```
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.cpp(40,25): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.cpp(50,33): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'GLclampf'
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.cpp(114,42): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.cpp(114,39): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.cpp(176,1): warning C4326: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vector3 __thiscall vector3::normalize(void)" (?normalize@vector3@@QAE?AV1@XZ) referenced in function "class vector3 __cdecl localColor(class vector3,class vector3,class vector3)" (?localColor@@YA?AVvector3@@V1@00@Z)
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vector3 __thiscall vector3::subtract(class vector3)" (?subtract@vector3@@QAE?AV1@V1@@Z) referenced in function "class vector3 __cdecl localColor(class vector3,class vector3,class vector3)" (?localColor@@YA?AVvector3@@V1@00@Z)
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall vector3::dot(class vector3)" (?dot@vector3@@QAEMV1@@Z) referenced in function "class vector3 __cdecl localColor(class vector3,class vector3,class vector3)" (?localColor@@YA?AVvector3@@V1@00@Z)
C:\Users\-\source\repos\OpenGL\OpenGL - TME3 -Q1 - Copy\Debug\OpenGL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is vector.cpp being compiled to an obj file? Also, what is an opengl file?

Comment: It looks like vector.cpp is not being compiled from what I understand of the error. OpenGl is a graphics library that I am using in this project to create the output.